# Launch file from isolated storage in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, document

My basic goal is like this:

1. Get document from URI
2. Save it to the isolated storage
3. Launch with default app

I have done all code very well,".PDF,.txt" document is also opening, but its content is not appearing. It remains blank. In case of ".docx", I am getting this message:

```
"Document has been damaged and can't be opened".
```

See my code below:

```
String file = "abc.pdf";
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.abc.com/abcd/getDocument");

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
wc.OpenReadCompleted += wc_OpenReadCompleted;

async void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
        await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0,(int)buffer.Length);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile(file, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }

        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync(file);

     // Launch the pdf file
     await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI is not correct. Try to use correct URI. This is the only problem. You can verify by bowing the used URI in browser. It does not exist.

Use the same respective extensions for all the files like .pdf for PDF file, for docx file use .docx extension